# How do I add vue.js client to an existing node.js api?

Tags: node.js, rest, vue.js, server

I have a node.js API with several endpoints that is working great. I have created a separate vue.js client app to manipulate data with the API I created. This is also working great. I have run into an issue where I need these apps to be running on the same port so a third party proxy system can access both these apps simultaneously.

I have seen a way to do this by copying the dist directory over to the node server but since I need this for a production env I need an alternative that dynamically builds the front end when building the node API as well.

Is there a production level alternative to adding a client app to run on an existing node server? Any recommendations or help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I've added this to my router file and have client and server in one project

```
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
   //production mode
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
  //
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname = '../client/dist/index.html'));
  })
}
//build mode
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../client/dist/index.html'));
})
```

Comment: Is you app based on Vue-cli or do you just include the vue.js file in your html ?

Comment: theres a vue-cli app and a express/node api - Im trying to run them on the same host(express/node) so the url is shared

Comment: I think using express static to expose the build directory would be the right approach here

Comment: thanks @StephenS the issue was that I was not pointing to the correct directory. I have a new error that says  "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:.../js/app.....js' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." I believe this is happening because even though those files are accessible vue-cli is still pointing to its internal server and that's causing issues. I think this might warrant a separate post, but if you have any input that would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than defining static routes in the route you could use it in the express app file as, `var app = express();app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist')));`
The files in dist should be the one built with vue-cli-service build.

Comment: thanks @StephenS this worked great, do you know why this might be returning a blank page? I can see the files in the dev console but the page is completely blank - this is what I have in the route file `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
  
    app.get('/app', (req, res) => {
        console.log(`dirname: `+ __dirname)
        //res.send('Ok')
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist/index.html"));
        
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose the dist directory built with vue-cli using a express static route. This directory should have your built assets along with index.html

```
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist'));
```

However, now since your application is not at the root directory you have to add a base url to your vue.config.js. Rebuild the app after this.

```
 module.exports = {
   publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/app/' : '',
   ...
   ...
   ...
 }
```

Now your vue app should be available at

> /app/index.html